# Can I manipulate the "Now Playing" queue in Windows Media Center using the SDK?

Tags: sdk, windows-media-center

I've downloaded the Windows Media Center SDK and have looked through the documentation, but I don't really see how I can interact with the "Now Playing" queue. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 you get full interaction. Use [MediaCollection](http://blog.retrosight.com/WindowsMediaCenterPlatformInThePDCBuildOfWindows7.aspx)

In Windows Vista stuff kind of works but its really fragile see [this code](http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/browse/trunk/MediaBrowser/Code/ModelItems/PlaybackController.cs).

Comment: I'm stuck with Vista for now - is there any way to get the current queue as a list, and also modify it (re-ordering, removing, etc)?

Comment: There is nothing built in. Its possible you could do something with com interop against the media player sdk, but you are looking at a major time sink figuring it out.

Comment: ewwwww yeah looks like it might be time to look into windows 7 then